# How much more disk space will require when Ubuntu 20.04 will be updated to 20.10?

Tags: updates

I have only 6 GB space left in my installed drive.
So, when I will update ubuntu does previous installed version would hold disk space?

Comment: Why do you want to upgrade to 20.10? It's lifetime is only 9 months, while the lifetime of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is 5 years

Comment: And in any your space left is insufficient to keep running the OS reliably.

Answer (score 2):

As [Ubuntu 20.10 is EOL](https://ubuntu-news.org/2021/07/25/ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-end-of-life-reached-on-july-22-2021/) the Ubuntu *release-upgrade* tools won't let you upgrade to it.

(*The upgrade tools will download https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release which you can view in a browser, and you'll note a `Supported: 0` which will tell your system that the 20.10 release is unsupported; thus Ubuntu tools won't allow upgrade to it*).

6GB maybe enough to let you upgrade; it'll depend on what & how many packages you have installed that need upgrade (ie. is your system *lean* or *bloated*..)

Once an upgrade is completed you can `apt autoremove` to reclaim space used during upgrade.